# Building a WMS QgsRasterLayer from a QgsDataSourceUri

Tags: raster, pyqgis, wms, uri

I have the following information for a WMS:

- Base-URL: http://example.com/wms
- CRS: EPSG:1234
- Format: image/png
- Layers: wms-layer

How can I use [`QgsDataSourceUri`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDataSourceUri.html) to create a WMS [`QgsRasterLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterLayer.html) from these? I do not want to construct a URL string manually but use the `QgsDataSourceUri` class.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `QgsDataSourceUri` is a class for storing the component parts of a RDBMS data source URI and not for creating raster layers.

Comment: I am trying to create my WMS layers similarly to my WFS layers. The docs of QgsDataSourceUri seem a bit outdated, at least https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html suggests using it for WFS and OGC API Features too (both no RDBMS). QgsRasterLayer can be created using a `uri: str`.

Comment: @christoph the doc for `QgsDataSourceUri` is a little misleading. It states "Class for storing the component parts of a RDBMS data source" but [other docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers) note `QgsDataSourceUri` can be use for other data sources.

Comment: @user2856 thanks for clarification. Didn't know the PostGIS Raster example in PyQGIS Cookbook, should check here more often ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manually added a WMS layer and looked at the URI as shown in the layer properties to work out what URI components are needed:

[image]

And based on [this example](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers) came up with the following which works in the QGIS python console:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

layer = "GEBCO"
uri_config = dict(
    layers="GEBCO_LATEST",
    crs="EPSG:4326",
    format="image/png",
    url="https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv"
)

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
for key, val in uri_config.items():
    uri.setParam(key, val)

layer = QgsRasterLayer(str(uri.encodedUri()), name, "wms")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```